# Python: selenium can't read an specific table

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I am trying to read and take the href for the elements from [this table](https://seia.sea.gob.cl/expediente/expedientesEvaluacion.php?modo=ficha&id_expediente=2148718463), but I can't I try selenium and urllib library but neither work:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:/Users/Public/chromedriver')
driver.get(str(link))
driver.implicitly_wait(30)
time.sleep(10)
try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 50).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "tabla_datos_linea"))
    )
    for a in driver.find_elements_by_partial_link_text('impacto'):
        print(a.text)
        
    
finally:
    driver.quit()
```

I exagerate in this code the conditions used to wait for the DOM to load with explicit and implicit wait, but still is not taking the table :(.
The output of this code is:

```
Expediente de evaluación de impacto ambiental
```

but I want this:

```
Expediente de evaluación de impacto ambiental
Estudio de impacto ambiental Firmado con certificado digital acreditado
```

Does anyone knows if this table has some trick or something? I used selenium other times without problem. And that place is public so I don't think it has some blockers or something.

thanks before hand!

Comment: are you sure you aint getting the one on top ? (xpath to it -> `/html/body/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr/td/div[1]/ul/li[2]/a/em`) ... I would recommend using for loop that will itterate through that table using xpath ... but in my opinion ... you will never get those data that are loaded by DOM ... I recommend you to try to use some JS Scripts (i have not seen selenium that is checking JS related stuff ... as far as I know it just grabs the HTML Content as a local variable and vavigates through it ... but i might be wrong)  Good luck tho ... I would got for that XPath :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inner table present inside an `iframe` and you need switch to `iframe` first in order to access the elements.

```
driver.get("https://seia.sea.gob.cl/expediente/expedientesEvaluacion.php?modo=ficha&id_expediente=2148718463")
elements=WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,".tabla_datos_linea ul.yui-nav a")))
for element in elements[1:]:
    print(element.text)
    print(element.get_attribute("href"))

WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.ID,"miFrame")))
elementsinnertable=WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,".tabla_datos_linea a[href^='https://seia.sea.gob.cl/documentos/documento.php']")))
for a in elementsinnertable:
    print(a.text)
    print(a.get_attribute("href"))
```

**Console Output:**

```
Expediente de evaluación de impacto ambiental
https://seia.sea.gob.cl/expediente/expedientesEvaluacion.php?modo=ficha&id_expediente=2148718463#-1
Participación ciudadana
https://seia.sea.gob.cl/expediente/expedientesEvaluacion.php?modo=ficha&id_expediente=2148718463#-1
Carta de envío texto radiodifusión
https://seia.sea.gob.cl/documentos/documento.php?idDocumento=2148718469
Extracto
https://seia.sea.gob.cl/documentos/documento.php?idDocumento=2148718470
Estudio de impacto ambiental
https://seia.sea.gob.cl/documentos/documento.php?idDocumento=2148718467
Resolución de Admisibilidad
https://seia.sea.gob.cl/documentos/documento.php?idDocumento=2148822701
Notificación de documento
https://seia.sea.gob.cl/documentos/documento.php?idDocumento=2148824474
Solicitud de evaluación de EIA
https://seia.sea.gob.cl/documentos/documento.php?idDocumento=2148834061
Solicitud de evaluación de EIA a gobierno regional
https://seia.sea.gob.cl/documentos/documento.php?idDocumento=2148834086
Solicitud de evaluación de EIA a municipalidad
https://seia.sea.gob.cl/documentos/documento.php?idDocumento=2148834093
```